# Grouped LongListSelector: headers appear, items don't

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

WinPhone 8 project in C#. I'm trying to populate a grouped list. The group headers appear, the items don't. The relevant code is:

```
class MyPage
{
    public class Group : IGrouping<string, string>
    {
        public string Title{get;set;}
        public string[] Items;

        public string Key
        {
            get { return Title; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (Items as IEnumerable<string>).GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Items.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    private Group[] m_ItemGroups =
        {
            new Group(){Title = "A", Items = new string[] {"A", "ASA"}},
            new Group(){Title = "X", Items = new string[] {"X", "XX"}},
        };

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TheList.ItemsSource = m_ItemGroups;
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<phone:LongListSelector
        x:Name="TheList"
        Grid.Row="1"
        IsGroupingEnabled="True"
        SelectionChanged="OnSelChanged"
        >

        <phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello world" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="345"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

    </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Neither of the `GetEnumerator()` methods is called. The `Key` getter is never called, either. Looks like the list does not recognize my `Group` class as a collection of strings that it is. Please, what's wrong here?

The item template is fine. When I change the list to non-grouped, I see two items with dummy text.

Replacing the `string` as the item type with a custom class does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `LongListSelector` expects, in grouped mode, that the objects in the `ItemsSource` collection implement `System.Collections.IList` (untyped). A simple `IEnumerator` won't do.

I wish that was documented. So far, WP8 SDK docs suck big time.

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. Could you post your implementation of the IList?

Comment: I've used an ObservableCollection of ObservableCollections after all. Didn't implement IList by hand.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev i have the same issue can you please help me on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986760/binding-data-in-longlistselector

Answer (score 5):

Seva is correct, Microsoft changed the type requirement for what you assign to the `ItemsSource` of a `LongListSelector` in the Grouped mode.

You need to convert whatever class you are using to group your items from inheriting `IEnumerable<T>` to just inheriting `List<T>`.

See [here for full description of answer](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth)

It's pretty simple actually, this is what an example of a Group class you could use with the **WP8** LongListSelector would look like:

```
    public class Group<T> : List<T>
{
    public Group(char name, IEnumerable<T> items) : base(items)
    {
        this.Letter = name;

    }



    public char Letter
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


}
```