# Binding data in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I am referring to the example here : http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-longlistselector-control

Here is my code :

```
public class Chapters
    {
        private string mainTitle;

        public string MainTitle
        {
            get { return mainTitle; }
            set { mainTitle = value; }
        }

        private List<string> subTitle;

        public List<string> SubTitle
        {
            get { return subTitle; }
            set { subTitle = value; }
        }


    }

private static IEnumerable<HighwayCode> GetCityList()
        {
            return myList;
             // Which already contains data:

              MainTitle : Chapters
              subtitle : ABC
              subtitle : X

              MainTitle : Chapters Two
              subtitle : ASDF
              subtitle : GHIJK

        }

        public class GroupingLayer<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
        {

            private readonly IGrouping<TKey, TElement> grouping;

            public GroupingLayer(IGrouping<TKey, TElement> unit)
            {
                grouping = unit;
            }

            public TKey Key
            {
                get { return grouping.Key; }
            }

            public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
            {
                return grouping.GetEnumerator();
            }

            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return grouping.GetEnumerator();
            }
        }
```

XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupHeader">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Padding="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTmpl">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" 
                       Foreground="Black" 
                       Text="{Binding SubTitle}"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="longListSelector"
                                    IsGroupingEnabled="True" LayoutMode="List" HideEmptyGroups="False"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTmpl}"
                                    GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeader}"/>
```

and i am setting it like this :

```
var selected = (from c in myList
                group c by c.MainTitle into n
                select new GroupingLayer<string, MyObject>(n)).ToList();

longListSelector.ItemsSource = selected;
```

But for me its only displaying the Main Title but Sub titles are not displaying at all.

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should set your items source to an observablecollection

I didn't do it exactly like you, but [here is my xaml](https://github.com/trsneed/StackOverflowCareersWinPho/blob/master/StackOverflowCareers/MainPage.xaml) and [here is a viewmodel](https://github.com/trsneed/StackOverflowCareersWinPho/blob/master/StackOverflowCareers/MainPage.xaml) for an app I build for the windows phone store.

I also believe it is key to clear and then set your items source on update. When I was building a WPF app, I seem to remember spending a lot of time trouble shooting the observablecollection not updating.

Comment: The collection needs to fire a CollectionChanged event for the Long List Selector to notice changes. Here's a blog post (coincidentally posted yesterday) from someone who ran into the same issue:  http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2014/02/swapped-listbox-for-longlistselector.html

You an use other collections such as List or IEnumerable, but you need to make sure it calls NotifyPropertyChanged after the items are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

> `var selected = (from c in myList
>                   group c by c.MainTitle into n
>                   select new GroupingLayer<string, MyObject>(n)).ToList();`

you get a list where every item has:

- a Key property (in your case containing MainTitle value) because you
  group by MainTitle!
- a list of "child" items

When you define your DataTemplate, you can bind the property "Key" because exists in this new list, but SubTitle does not exists, so you can't show it!

You can take a look at this sample:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PhotoHub-Windows-Phone-8-fd7a1093

Comment: How can i fix that in my case ? can you please help me ?, what all do i need to change here?