# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable GroupingLayer to 'System.Collections.IList'

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I have this code :

```
var selected = from c in myList group c by c.MainTitle into n select new GroupingLayer<string, MyObject>(n);
            longListSelector.ItemsSource = selected; //Error here


public class GroupingLayer<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
        {

            private readonly IGrouping<TKey, TElement> grouping;

            public GroupingLayer(IGrouping<TKey, TElement> unit)
            {
                grouping = unit;
            }

            public TKey Key
            {
                get { return grouping.Key; }
            }

            public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
            {
                return grouping.GetEnumerator();
            }

            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return grouping.GetEnumerator();
            }
        }
```

What does its trying to  tell me ?, how to solve this ?

I am Working on windows Phone 8 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that [`longListSelector.ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.itemssource%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is of type `IList`, but the value stored in `selected` is an `IEnumerable`, and you can't assign one to the other.

Try calling `ToList()`:

```
var selected = (from c in myList
                group c by c.MainTitle into n
                select new GroupingLayer<string, MyObject>(n)).ToList();

longListSelector.ItemsSource = selected;
```

Comment: please have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986760/binding-data-in-longlistselector

Comment: Did you have a look at it ?

Comment: Can you please have  have a look at it here  ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986760/binding-data-in-longlistselector ... No one has answered till now, can you please help me on that